# why iterating a received generic HashMap can only be done with enhanced for-loop?

Tags: java, generics

I am implementing a putAll() method.
I tried to iterate the map using entrySet and iterator methods, but received a compiling error that `m.entrySet().iterator()` return value could not be converted to `Iterator<Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`.
why? if the map is of that type, it's iterator should be as well, no?

thank you!
doesn't compile:

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {       
        Iterator<Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> iter = m.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry = iter.next();
        put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

compiles and works fine:

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(m, "putAll(): argument is null");

    for (Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your other attempt was wrong. Please ask what you actually mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Iterator<Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> iter
```

To

```
Iterator<? extends Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> iter
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way, each time the method is called, `m`, which has type `Map<? extends K, ? extends V>`, points to an object with a "real" type of `Map<some actual subtype of K we don't know, some actual subtype of V we don't know>`. (These unknown types might be different in each call of the method, but in each call, the passed object must have some specific type for each of the type parameters, though we don't know it.)

Therefore, `m.entrySet().iterator()` has type `Iterator<Map.Entry<some unknown subtype of K, some unknown subtype of V>>`. This is not a subtype of `Iterator<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`, because when the top-level type argument is not a wildcard, the top-level type arguments must match exactly, and they don't here.

`Iterator<Map.Entry<some unknown subtype of K, some unknown subtype of V>>` is not a subtype of `Iterator<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>` even though `Map.Entry<some unknown subtype of K, some unknown subtype of V>` is a subtype of `Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>`, just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

One solution is to add a wildcard at the top level, like in Lino's answer: `Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>`.